# What is normal flow coming from icemaker tubing?

Tags: ice-maker

Could someone give me a description of what normal flow of water should be coming from water supply through icemaker tubing. It is 1/4 od plastic tubing that is traveling approximately 10 feet from water supply. What I mean is should water be coming out in a steady stream, fast drip, slow drip, etc?

Comment: It should be a solid Pee many fridg's use saddle valves to make the connection, this cheap method of connection has been the cause of almost all the low flow , no flow and leaks that I have found over a few decades.

Comment: I would say mine is a slow-medium drip. It would take a while to fill a cup.

Answer (score 1):

It should come in a steady stream. Some refrigerator user manuals state "filling a cup of water in 10 seconds".

Typically it is recommended (or even stated) to use copper tubing and not plastic. I do not know if this has any real impact on flow, especially with just 10' away.

Comment: Plastic lines are fine, pex is plastic many of the supplies I have installed have a plastic liner in stainless mesh , I also use soft copper tubing but sometimes the plastic lines are more feasible , most the problems 95%+ has been with the saddle valves used to tap the lines only a few % have been the solenoid on the fridge.

Comment: If you have a saddle valve supplying the water, try turning the saddle valve past the closed point. When you close the valve, it has a sharp end that punctures the copper. You may need to turn the saddle valve a little further closed to pierce a larger hole in the copper it is mounted on.

Comment: There was a kink in part of line that was under house. I cut it out of line and redid fitting and have good flow now.